# remove specific sysctl.conf setting

Tags: sed, grep, sysctl

on some of my machines i have this block of setting in sysctl.conf(the numbers are different on each machine) :

```
#Size Of RAM (In GB):   23
kernel.shmmni=  2547
kernel.shmmax=  365482458
kernel.shmall=  25471984
#kernel.sem=<SEMMSL> <SEMMNS> <SEMOPM> <SEMMNI>
kernel.sem=     325     12496852  74      3654
kernel.msgmni=  1204
kernel.msgmax=  57452
kernel.msgmnb=  74235
```

the location of this block is different sometimes. i wanted to write a bash that remove this old settings and insert new configuration. since it is sysctl.conf i need to do it safely. how i can remove them with `sed` or `grep` and be sure that only this block will remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the only place in the file where those lines appear:

```
sed '/#Size Of RAM (In GB):   23/,/kernel.msgmnb/d' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

That searches for everything in between and including the first and last lines of that block and deletes it. I included the first line in its entirety instead of a smaller string in case `Size` or something else in it appears elsewhere in the file. I have also used `kernel.msgmnb` as you've stated that the number is different on other machines.

That command will send the changes to stdout so that you can make sure that the changes are what you want. If they are, you can do an inplace edit of the file by adding the `-i` switch:

```
sed -i '/#Size Of RAM (In GB):   23/,/kernel.msgmnb/d' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: this `kernel.msgmnb` exist in configuration file. it won't make mistakes, does it?

Comment: @BlackCrystal No. It will look for the first instances of `#Size Of RAM (In GB):   23` and `kernel.msgmnb=  74235`. `kernel.msgmnb` is not identical to your last line so even if it were in that block of text around the middle, the commands would still work. Give the first command without the `-i` switch a try  to make sure that it does what you want as it will only sends the changes to stdout.

Comment: numbers are different on each machine. i can't use `kernel.msgmnb= 74235`. i should use `kernel.msgmnb`. that's why i asked.

Comment: @BlackCrystal You can do it that way. It will still work as long as long as the block looks like what you have above and `kernel.msgmnb` doesn't appear inside of that code block before it does on the last line. See my update.

Comment: @NasirRiley OP also asked for the script to insert new settings, would you consider using the "c \ " switch for `sed` to replace the entire block of text with the new settings?